# SQL: selecting a value based on values from a number of rows in another table

Tags: sql

I have a table NETWORKS where each network can have multiple CIRCUITS. Each network has an over-all status (red/yellow/green) and each circuit has an individual status (red/green). The circuit's statuses are each set manually. The network's status is as such:

- If all its circuits are green --> Green
- If all its circuits are red --> Red
- If at least 1, but not all, circuits are green --> Yellow
- If there are no circuits --> NULL(no status)

I am trying to select all of the networks with their statuses being determined dynamically by the SELECT rather than having to save and manage the status as a column in the table. I cannot figure out an efficient way to do this. What I have now works (both are small tables, < 100, rows with a relatively static amount of data), but is wildly inefficient and I'm hoping there is a better way.

```
SELECT
(CASE 
    WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM NETWORK_CIRCUITS 
        WHERE network_id = N.network_id
    ) = 0 THEN 'noStatus'
    WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM NETWORK_CIRCUITS 
        WHERE network_id = N.network_id
        AND [status] = 'greenStatus'
    ) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM NETWORK_CIRCUITS 
        WHERE network_id = SSN.network_id
    ) THEN 'greenStatus'
    WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM NETWORK_CIRCUITS 
        WHERE network_id = N.network_id
        AND [status] = 'redStatus'
    ) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM NETWORK_CIRCUITS 
        WHERE network_id = N.network_id
    ) THEN 'redStatus'
    ELSE 'yellowStatus'
END) network_status
FROM NETWORKS N
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN CircuitCount IS NULL      THEN 'noStatus'
        WHEN GreenCount = CircuitCount THEN 'greenStatus'
        WHEN GreenCount = 0            THEN 'redStatus'
        ELSE 'yellowStatus'
    END As network_status
FROM NETWORKS As N
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT  COUNT(*) As CircuitCount,
            COUNT(NULLIF([status],'redStatus')) As GreenCount,
            network_id
    FROM    NETWORK_CIRCUITS
    GROUP BY network_id
)   As C    ON N.network_id = C.network_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want.  It should also be faster than using a bunch of subqueries.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN circuits.network_id is NULL THEN 'No Status'
         WHEN circuits.greenCount = circuits.totalCircuits THEN 'Green'
         WHEN circuits.greenCount >= 1 and circuits.redCount >= 1 THEN 'Yellow'
         WHEN circuits.redCount = circuits.totalCircuits THEN 'Red'
       END as network_status
      , N.network_id
FROM NETWORKS N
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT network_id
           , sum(CASE WHEN [status] = 'redStatus' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as redCount
           , sum(CASE WHEN [status] = 'greenStatus' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as greenCount
           , count(*) as totalCircuits
    FROM NETWORK_CIRCUITS
    GROUP BY network_id) as circuits ON circuits.network_id = N.network_id
```

Comment: I downvoted this by accident, sorry (flaky mouse). If you'll make some minor edit to it, I can change my vote...

Comment: @RBarryYoung Edited my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is:

```
select network_id, case when green=0 and red=0 then null when green=0 then 'red' else when red=0 then 'green' else 'yellow' end as status
from
(select n.network_id,
  sum(case when c.status='green' then 1 else 0 end) as green,
  sum(case when c.status='red' then 1 else 0 end) as red
from network n
join circuit c on c.network_id=n.network_id
group by n.network_id)
```

Comment: Oops, should be "left join circuit" or we'll never get the null status case.